# Thread.Suspend is obsolete

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, suspend

What alternative for Thread.Resume() and Thread.Suspend() in vb.net

```
Private Sub StartServiceToolStrip_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles StartServiceToolStrip.Click
    Using login As New Login
        If (login.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.Cancel) Then
            Return
        End If
        ClientNotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(100, " Network", " Network service has been started...", ToolTipIcon.Info)
        StartServiceToolStrip.Enabled = False
        StopServiceToolStrip.Enabled = True
        receiveThread.Resume()
    End Using

End Sub
```

> Warning   1   'Public Sub Suspend()' is obsolete: 'Thread.Suspend has been deprecated.  Please use other classes in System.Threading, such as Monitor, Mutex, Event, and Semaphore, to synchronize Threads or protect resources.'.

Getting This error

Comment: It's clearly in the message....what to use. So what's the issue? Also in my opinion use a AutoResetEvent... In short the worker thread will in turn wait on the wait handle until another thread calls another method that calls `Set` on the EventWaitHandle.

Comment: i add some details above sir

Comment: Ok, as mentioned use an AutoResetEvent. ***Do not use .Suspend or .Resume***. I think this was depreciated after 2.0 framework. The reason is because you can't figure out if you're calling Resume when the thread could be suspended. On another note if your using `Suspend` somewhere then it's possible that it could suspend the thread while it was holding a lock on a mutex...bad idea.

Comment: Please do not put the programming language in the title unless it really [fits in there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles). Related languages, libraries, APIs, etc. belong in the tags.